# Jest Mock Function not working when mocking an async function containing fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, mocking

**File src/api/index.ts**

```
export const compositeScore = async (queryParams, platform) => {
    const compositeScore = await fetchWrapper(
        platform.concat("CompositeScore"),
        queryParams,
        getPlatfromDB(platform),
        getPlatfromURL(platform)
    );
    return compositeScore;
};
```

**File src/api/index.ts**

```
export async function fetchWrapper(
    queryName: string,
    queryParams?: {},
    dbName?: string,
    url: string = WEB_URL
) {
    // await acquireToken();
    const token = await getToken();
    const headers = {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Host: "********************",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    };
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "post",
        headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            db: dbName || WEB_DB,
            csl: queryParams
                ? substituteQueryParameters(queries[queryName], queryParams)
                : queries[queryName],
        }),
    });
}
```

**File src/**mocks**/index.ts**

```
const compositeScore = async (queryParams, platform) => {
    const compositeScore = await fetchWrapper(
        platform.concat("CompositeScore"),
        queryParams
    );
    console.log("Called");
    return Promise.resolve("Yay");
};
export default compositeScore;
```

**File src/api/index.test.ts**

```
import "jest";
import { compositeScore } from "./index";
jest.mock("../__mocks__/index");
describe("Unit Test for API Calls", () => {
    it("Try async calls", async () => {
        // console.log("G");
        // const response =  await fetchWrapper1("A", "B");
        const response = await compositeScore("A", "B");
        expect(response).toBe("Ya");
    });
});
```

**When I run jest , I get the error :**

ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

```
  47 |         "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  48 |     };
> 49 |     return fetch(url, {
     |     ^
  50 |         method: "post",
  51 |         headers,
  52 |         body: JSON.stringify({

  at src/api/index.ts:49:5
  at fulfilled (src/api/index.ts:5:58)
```

I am not sure why Jest is not calling the mock function of compositeScore. Can anyone point out the reason?

Comment: I think you have to provide a mockImplementation for it. Could you try `jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockResolvedValue(() => dummyData)`?

Comment: I am afraid this is not working

Comment: You are testing `compositeScore`, you should mock the functions it uses rather than itself.